# code rewriting in jquery based upon select selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

it 99% working, where it is failing to add the attribute of required to the input field. when a certain condition matches and also it should run of page load even if the value of select is not changed.

and if the value of select is changed then also it should run.

Here is my Javascript code try

```
var e = document.getElementById("StatusID");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var _cost = document.getElementById('_total');
if(_cost.value == 0) {
    $(".Star").css('display','inline-block');
    _cost.setAttribute("required", "");
} 
else {
    $(".Star").css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: Unclear: you have some jquery and the code provided is the js attempt? (if so, where's the jquery)  Or you have some js (provided) and you want us to write the jquery for you? (if so... where's the jquery you've tried?)

Comment: i do not have jquery, and that is what i am planning to use, i wrote the raw javascript

Comment: Part 2: run on page load, see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Part1: `$(related_input).attr("required","required");` - there's some other questions on SO, but some incorrectly use "prop()" or suggested alternatives (I didn't [look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+set+attribute+required) too hard)

Comment: @Regual you've written a mix of vanilla JS and jQuery. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve] so we can help debug it.

Comment: Add a change event handler and call the code

Comment: from comments: "*i added the wrong [code]*" - please [edit] the question and add a *complete* [mcve] which includes the relevant inputs along with what you're expecting to happen and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated:

You should add change event for `StatusID`:

```
var e = document.getElementById("StatusID");
e.onchange = function() {
    changeHandler();
};

window.onload = function() {
    changeHandler();
};

function changeHandler() {
    var _cost = document.getElementById('_total');
    var e = document.getElementById("StatusID");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(_cost.value == 0) {
        $(".Star").css('display','inline-block');
        _cost.setAttribute("required", "");
    } 
    else {
        $(".Star").css('display','none');
    }
}
```

In the above (and this update), you do not need to enter the code before closing body tag.

Comment: >> or load page issue, you should add this code before end of body tag. can you explian this what you are saying

Comment: and what if i want to use struser instead of cost or both

Comment: the onChange to be added to the struser and then the Attribute is added to the _cost

Comment: @Regual updated my answer for that. but for load page issue, for run JavaScript code as soon as the page elements are loaded completely, the code should be inserted before the `</body>`.

Comment: i cannot add onchange on _cost.onchange, it has to be on StrUser because that is the select box

Comment: _cost is the hidden field

Comment: i added the wrong which is _cost.setAttribute that should  not be there

Comment: @Regual the select box that change `_cost`?

Comment: the selectbox is StatusID and once the StatusID changes, it displays the css class to display/hide and that same needs to be onload where onload will detect what is the cost and based upon that, it will do display hide and show, it should work on onchange event and onload event both

Comment: @Regual I updated my answer with new code, I hope the problem is solved. in this update, you do not need to enter the code before closing body tag.